# colorir um datatable utilizando data

Tags: java, primefaces

estou apenas testando, quero deixar a fonte vermelha se a data for menor ou igual ao dia de hoje

mas nao está acontecendo nada
tentei com '2017-02-21' '21/02/2017' e nao funciona

meu css:

```
.vermelho {
    color: red;
}
```

meu datatable:

```
<p:inputMask value="#{con.vencimento}" style="width:96%"
                            rowStyleClass="#{con.vencimento le '2017-02-21' ? 'vermelho' : null}"                           
                                mask="99/99/9999" label="vencimento">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar o `rowStyleClass`. Tente usar o `styleClass`.

Comment: Outra pergunta: Qual o valor de `con.vencimento`?